# How to discover unpaired Bluetooth devices in a Windows 10 tablet application without using the settings app

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth, windows-10-universal, bluetooth-device-discovery

I wonder if it is possible to discover unpaired Bluetooth devices programmatically within a Windows 10 tablet application.

I really don't want to pair by **Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth**.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation/example that would have helped.

I tried to search for Bluetooth devices by using the **BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher** but I wasn't able to find any. Probably because these devices were no BluetoothLE devices. Thought these were compatible.

Also I thought it would be possible to create a CLI/C++ wrapper that I could reuse in my UWP application but I feel very uncertain about that as not the whole (especially the interfacing part of the) Win32 API is re-usable in UWP environment.

At a last option I thought there must be a way to just get the list of devices that Windows generates when entering **Settings -> Devices -> Bluetooth** and I tried to achieve that by using a **DeviceWachter** but without success.

Now I am very desperate. For my application it would be horrible to manually pair each and every device before using it. I cannot understand why Microsoft cuts the developers so enormous.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if it is possible to discover unpaired Bluetooth devices programmatically within a Windows 10 tablet application.

Yes, it's possible.

> I tried to search for Bluetooth devices by using the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher but I wasn't able to find any. Probably because these devices were no BluetoothLE devices.

You used a wrong watcher. What you need is [DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), not [BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher.aspx). The difference between them is that the `DeviceWatcher` is for enumerating devices dynamically, while the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` is for receiving Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) advertisements.

There is an official [Device enumeration and pairing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing), you can refer to scenario 8 of this sample, this sample is absolutely what you need.

Comment: How does the `DeviceWatcher` discover unpaired BLE devices? It must listen to BLE advertisements under the hood, mustn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Grace's answer is correct. I tried this sample before but stopped working on it as it expected a Windows Phone instead of a Windows 10 tablet.

Now I extracted the DeviceWatcher part but created the DeviceWatcher with the selector **BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false)**. Only with this selecter the watcher was able to finde unpaired Bluetooth devices.

It also works with:

```
DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(false))
```

Comment: Worked great!! Thanks.